# Формат web-страницы

Tags: веб-программирование

Стало интересно, как получаются страницы вот в таком формате: `http://vk.com/audio`?
Какое расширение у страницы `audio(.php?, .html?)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Веб серверы часто настроены более сложно, чем просто на выдачу файлов из папок по их настоящему имени. По большому счёту, в ответ на любой запрос, веб сервер может выдать всё что ему угодно. Запрашиваешь `http://site.com/index.html`, а получаешь в ответ картинку GIF, если так задумано владельцами сервера.

Браузер общается с веб-сервером по протоколу [HTTP](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP). Беседуют они обычно примерно так:

**Браузер**: "Привет, [www.site.ru](http://www.site.ru), дай страницу `/about.html` "

**Сервер**: "Привет, да, есть такая, держи. Это будет `text/html`, длиной `40к`, в кодировке `UTF-8`, ну ты разберёшься. Да, я кстати `Apache/2.2`"

И дальше сразу же Сервер выдаёт собственно текст страницы.

Чтобы узнать, что же там выдаёт искомую страницу, можно поэкспериментировать. Например предположить, что `/audio` в этом вопросе, это имя папки. После запроса `vk.com/audio` попробовать ещё и `vk.com/audio/index.php` и если результат будет идентичен предыдущему, значит, предположение про `index.php`, лежащий в папке `/audio` оказалось верным.

Answer (score 2):

[Краткое руководство по htaccess и mod_rewrite](http://www.seoblog.com.ua/2008/11/04/kratkoe-rukovodstvo-po-htaccess-and-mod_rewrite/)

Comment: Ну и давайте грузанём ещё ТС nginx'ом заодно, ведь фронтендом на VK стоит именно он : )   [nginx HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule#rewrite)